# Classification of data in R

Tags: r, data.table

I want to evaluate all the values when I have a flag set to one. In the following example I want to do 2 evaluations:

- Which "input" is lower from line 1 to line 3, evaluating 1st line, 2nd line and 3rd line "input"-s.
- Which "input" is lower from line 5 to line 7, evaluating 5th line, 6th line and 7th line "input"-s.

I want to show the "input2" value of the lowest value of "input" on the column out and the rest of the values on column "rest".

This is my input data

```r
flag <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,1)
input<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
input2<- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
library(data.table)
data.dt <- data.table(flag,input, input2)
data.dt
#>    flag input input2
#> 1:    0     1      a
#> 2:    1     2      b
#> 3:    1     3      c
#> 4:    0     4      d
#> 5:    0     5      e
#> 6:    1     6      f
#> 7:    1     7      g
```

I want to obtain this result:

```r
    flag    input    input2      out    rest
      0       1        a          -       -
      1       2        b          a       b
      1       3        c          a       b,c
      0       4        d          -       -
      0       5        e          -       -
      1       6        f          e       f
      1       7        g          e       f,g
```

Comment: Because the flag value in the next column is 0

Comment: Did you meant the flag value in the next row is 0?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the next row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option

```
data.dt[,  grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(flag) < 0))]
i1 <- data.dt[, .I[!(shift(flag, type = 'lead') == 0 & flag == 0)], .(grp)]$V1
i2 <- data.dt[, .I[flag == 0]]
i3 <- setdiff(i1, i2)
data.dt[i1,  out := input2[flag == 0], .(grp)]
 data.dt[i2, out := NA]
v2 <- data.dt[i1, {v1 <- input2[flag == 1];sapply(seq_along(v1), 
      function(i) toString(v1[seq_len(i)]))}, .(grp)]$V1
data.dt[i3, rest := v2][, grp := NULL][]
#    flag input input2  out rest
#1:    0     1      a <NA> <NA>
#2:    1     2      b    a    b
#3:    1     3      c    a b, c
#4:    0     4      d <NA> <NA>
#5:    0     5      e <NA> <NA>
#6:    1     6      f    e    f
#7:    1     7      g    e f, g
```

Comment: I run that code and I have the following error:
```
Error in `[.data.table`(data.dt, i3, `:=`(rest, v2)) : 
  i3 is not found in calling scope and it is not a column of type logical. When the first argument inside DT[...] is a single symbol, data.table looks for it in calling scope.
```

Comment: @lpa  I am not getting the error with the example you provided.  Tried again and still no error

Comment: I've tried it again and I'm still obtaining the error I told you.

Comment: @lpa  I can't reproduce your error.  Even if  I used your example on;y

Comment: Executing the code one line by one y obtain this error:
`
> i1 <- data.dt[, .I[!(shift(flag, type = 'lead') == 0 & flag == 0)], .(grp)]$V1
Error in shift(flag, type = "lead") : unused argument (type = "lead")
`

Comment: @lpa What is your data.table version?  I used `packageVersion('data.table')
[1] ‘1.12.2’`  Also, have you loaded any other package with `shift` function.  In that case, you may need `data.table::shift`

Comment: @lpa How do you want to take into account.  Can you post as a new question

Comment: hello, I want to make a modification on the code, but I barely understand it. I want to take into account the column "input". I want to save in the column out the value of "input2" whose "input" value
{
#    flag input input2      out       rest
#1:    0     2      a          <NA>   <NA>
#2:    1     1      b            b            a
#3:    1     3      c            b            a,  c
#4:    0     4      d           <NA> <NA>
#5:    0     5      e           <NA> <NA>
#6:    1     6      f              e           f
#7:    1     7      g             e          f, g
}

Comment: @lpa Can you please post as a new question as it may take some effort and from the comments, it is not clear